# Triple switch wiring, only two wires

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I have an older triple switch (fan, light, power), that has only two black wires, both hot.

I am trying to wire it to a new triple switch, that has a hot post on one side and three posts on the other side.

How do I wire this new switch to those two existing hot wires so one operates the power, one the fan and the other the light??

Comment: They can't both be hot, but one can come from source and one goes to the light with the neutral coming from some other direction.  I'm not an electrician, but I don't know of any way to do what you want without running another wire from the switch box to the light.

Comment: Pictures of the existing switch & wiring, plus a picture of the new switch will help immensely.

Comment: Something does NOT add up. Each thing that needs independent power would have its own wire supplying power from the switch.  More info is needed.

Comment: It sounds like either electronics is involved, or someone did something really dangerous.

Comment: Can you please post photos of the wiring involved?

Comment: Here are the photos, includes the switch that came out, the wiring, and the switch going in.

https://prnt.sc/10d5w9k
https://prnt.sc/10d5wvr
https://prnt.sc/10d5xdw
https://prnt.sc/10d5xwb

Comment: Are you OK with taking that triple switch back and getting a fan controller instead?

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though you are replacing a fan/light switch- this is not a triple switch hence the different wiring on the new replacement triple switch you have.

You need to replace this with a similar Casblanca fan/ light  switch for things to function properly with your ceiling fan.

Comment: Thank You so much! That is exactly what I want, but never heard of it. I certainly appreciate all the help!

Comment: @MichaelCopping if you'll take the [tour], you'll see that the proper way to say "thank you" is to click the up arrow next to any answer that helps you, and the check mark next to the one that helps you _the most_. This one is easy since there's only one answer.